# matching pattern on the string using loop without regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, string-matching

i want to match pattern on the string using for loop and i create code like this :

```
function partialCheck(str, partial) {
  
  var pattern = [];
  for (var i =0; i <= str.length; i++){
    if(partial === str[i]+str[i+1]+str[i+2]){
      pattern.push(partial);
    }
  }
  return pattern;
}
```

on the test case, it should show the result like this :

> console.log(partialCheck('abcdcabdabc', 'abc')); // ["abc","abc"]
>
> console.log(partialCheck('accHghebchg', 'chg')); // ["cHg","chg"]

but on second case, it resulted like this :

> console.log(partialCheck('accHghebchg', 'chg')); // ["chg"]

the question is it possible to put cHg to the array by ignoring case sensivity without using regex?

thanks before.

Comment: Use `toLowerCase()` on both sides of `===`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and you can use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to make the code simpler:

```
function partialCheck(str, partial) {

  var pattern = [];
  partial = partial.toLowerCase();
  for (var i =0; i <= str.length; i++){
    var substr = str.substring(i, i + 3);
    if(partial === substr.toLowerCase()){
      pattern.push(substr);
    }
  }
  return pattern;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to lowercase before comparing.

You can also use `substr()` instead of concatenating specific indexes of the string. This allows you to work with any size `partial`.

And you should push the substring onto the result array, not `partial`, so that you get the case from the string.

```js
function partialCheck(str, partial) {
  var pattern = [];
  partial = partial.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i <= str.length - partial.length; i++) {
    if (partial === str.substr(i, partial.length).toLowerCase()) {
      pattern.push(str.substr(i, partial.length));
    }
  }
  return pattern;
}

console.log(partialCheck('accHghebchg', 'chg'));
```